# Is it right to say that: if $2a+1=2b$ we have a contradiction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, parity

I am trying to prove by contradiction and I have reached the conclusion that $2a+1=2b$. Now I am tempted to say it's a contradiction and call it a night. Is it a contradiction? because one is even and the other is odd?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know that $a$ and $b$ are integers, then yes, it’s a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct if $a$ and $b$ are integers: You can rearrange to write

$$1 = 2(b - a)$$

Hence either $1 = 0$ or $2 | 1$, either of which is bad.

Comment: I can see why 2|1 but how do you conclude that 1=0 from the equation 1=2(b−a)? Thanks for the response

Comment: @Reboot_87 Either $a = b$ or $a \ne b$. Handle the cases separately.

Comment: Got it. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're right. It's a contradiction exactly because of what you said: "one is even and one is odd". This gives rise to a contradiction because the sets of odd numbers and even numbers are disjoint. In other words, a number can't be both even and odd at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a contradiction if it's not an integral domain...

Comment: Of course It's a contradiction if you look at the definition of odd and even numbers as a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Come again? @some1.new4u

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by come again?